# memory error with big dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory

I have a big dataframe with huge number of rows approx 9 millions of records
I try to filter this dataframe with this code:

```
cadata = cadata[cadata['START_DATE']<cadata['OPP_CREATION_DATE']]
```

But I get a memory error

I try with : 
`cadata = cadata.query("START_DATE < OPP_CREATION_DATE")` but I get the same memory problem 
Can you help me to avoid this problem
Thank you

Comment: How big? Or is that a secret we aren't allowed to know?

Comment: the dataframe contains 9 million records. I try with cadata = `cadata.query("START_DATE < OPP_CREATION_DATE")` but I get the same memory problem